# How to customize cron job in ruby application?

Tags: ruby, cron, padrino

I have been developing a backend with padrino ruby framework and I would like to build a cron job.

This is what I have done.

- `gem 'whenever', :require => false`
- `wheneverize .`

**inside schedule.rb**

```
 every 1.minute do
    rake "cronjob"
 end
```

**/tasks/cronjob.rake**

Here I added my custom tasks. and this will be to long to add here.

So I wrote only error happening parts

```
performances = Performance.left_join(:slots, id: :slot_id).where(Sequel.~(status: ModelA::Api.settings.pending),Sequel[:slots][:from]>oneweekbefore,Sequel[:slots][:to]<onemonthafter+1.day)
....

begin
  data = {}
  data[:from] = "** <postmaster@**.mailgun.org>"
  data[:to] = email
  data[:subject] = subject
  data[:html] = render 'mails/sendemailbasedontime',:locals => { :data => localdata }
  RestClient.post GigabitArtist::Api.settings.mailgun_domain, data
    rescue => exception
      puts exception.inspect
    end
end
```

I got these errors:

> SEQUEL DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing multiple arguments as filter
>   arguments when not using a conditions specifier
>   ([#:!=, @args=>[:status,
>   "pending"]>, #:>,
>   @args=>[#"slots",
>   @column=>:from>, Sat, 02 Dec 2017]>, #:<, @args=>[#"slots",
>   @column=>:to>, Wed, 10 Jan 2018]>]) is deprecated and will be removed
>   in Sequel 5.  Pass the arguments to separate filter methods or use
>   Sequel.& to combine them.
>       /Users/whitesnow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sequel-4.46.0/lib/sequel/dataset/query.rb:1296:in
>   `filter_expr'
>       /Users/whitesnow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sequel-4.46.0/lib/sequel/dataset/query.rb:1249:in`
>   add_filter'
>       /Users/whitesnow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sequel-4.46.0/lib/sequel/dataset/query.rb:1034:in
>   `where'
>       /Volumes/Data/Work/RBP/GAB/tasks/cronjob.rake:12:in`block in '
>       /Users/whitesnow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in
>   `block in execute'
>       /Users/whitesnow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in`
>   each'
>       /Users/whitesnow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in
>   `execute'
>       /Users/whitesnow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in`
>   block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>       /Users/whitesnow/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>       /Users/whitesnow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'

I think errors are from `sequel querying` and

```
data[:html] = render 'mails/sendemailbasedontime',:locals => { :data => localdata }
```

ofcourse, this query was tested in other .rb file and I tested with raw sql. for example, I tested this tasks inside get request hander of test.rb controller. and it does work well
I would like to know if I can use render function inside task.
I searched all day for this problem with no success.
Any advice will be big help for me.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the deprecation warning states, you are passing multiple arguments to a filter method.  The simplest fix would be to call a filter method separately for each argument:

```
performances = Performance.
  left_join(:slots, id: :slot_id).
  exclude(status: ModelA::Api.settings.pending).
  where(Sequel[:slots][:from]>oneweekbefore).
  where(Sequel[:slots][:to]<onemonthafter+1.day)
```